# I am trying to run a query in access. When I set up a parameter using the IIF function it is not working properly. It is not reading the string

Tags: ms-access

I have set up an adjustment log that tracks all of the adjustments that go in and out of a system. The database serves as an approval database and it gives reason codes for every transaction.

Now, after the fact, I am trying to determine the number of transactions that have occurred by reason code.

(In access) after pulling in the necessary Fields, I typed this as a parameter in a query.

Inventory Short Descrepency: IIf([Reason Code]="Inventory Short Discrepency 
    ",1,0)

When I move from design mode to view mode the IIF function does not work. It shows zeros down the board.

If I was to do this in excel it would work fine, but I am trying to make it work here in MS Access. I can export this to excel, but I am trying to roll this up into a report that I can generate weekly.

Is there something that I am missing?

Respectfully,

TYMO

Comment: Looks like a space after Discrepency. But I just did a test and trailing space(s) are ignored. Don't see anything wrong with this expression. Edit question to show sample data and well as entire SQL. Why not just an aggregate query that groups on [Reason Code]? Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calcs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is with text comparison which is always a bad idea to depend on. Your Reason Codes should be ID numbers from a lookup table, not text. For example the correct spelling is "Discrep**a**ncy" which could account for why you get zero matches but also demonstrate why text comparison has so much potential for failure.

Comment: The reason code field is populated by choosing a record from a different table. ( validation table) ** Funny because its spelled wrong** In doing so the field's actual value is the primary key of the validation table. In this case. the record shows" inventory Short discrepancy" but its actual value is "8".  I'm having to play around with this database and I did not lay out all the factors properly. I was given this database and  I am still learning.. Thank you all for your time.